# Am I missing a tmp file? Heroku deployment error ENOENT

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I've scoured Google and SO pasting each line in and trying the provided solutions, to no avail. These solutions I've tried include: **updating NPM, re-installing node_modules, creating a blank .npmignore file and making sure node version is in package.json**,  among others. I've included the command-line response I get when trying to push my app to Heroku. I'm not able to find the tmp file that is being referenced, so I feel this is the main culprit and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.4
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall chmod
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_5a3f35f2b4044705fefebef727074f14/node_modules/protobufjs/bin/pbts
remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/build_5a3f35f2b4044705fefebef727074f14/node_modules/protobufjs/bin/pbts'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        npm ERR! enoent
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.jDRDQ/_logs/2020-05-23T20_48_45_290Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to algebra-1-assessment.
remote:
```